# How to represent Bitxor to mod in matlab

Tags: matlab, bit-manipulation, modulus, bitwise-xor

I want to implement xor bitwise together. For example, I have two bits pair that are 6 (110) and 3 (011). Now I want to implement bitwise xor of two inputs. It can do by bitxor function in matlab.

```
out=bitxor(6,3);%output is 5
```

But I want to implement the scheme by mod function instead of bitxor. How to do it by matlab?Thank you so much. it is my code

```
out=mod(6+3,2^3) %2^3 because Galois field is 8 (3 bits)
```

Comment: Curious if the answer provided here work for you? If it did, consider accepting it, so that it could be considered here in Stackoverflow as "closed".

Answer (score 3):

**Code**

```
function out = bitxor_alt(n1,n2)

max_digits = ceil(log(max(n1,n2)+1)/log(2));%// max digits binary representation

n1c = dec2bin(n1,max_digits); %// first number as binary in char type
n2c = dec2bin(n2,max_digits); %// second number as binary in char type

n1d = n1c-'0'; %// first number as binary in double type
n2d = n2c-'0'; %// second number as binary in double type

out = bin2dec(num2str(mod(n1d+n2d,2),'%1d')); %// mod used here

return;
```

Comment: Darnit!  I was about to write an answer.  You beat me to it... again :P.  This was basically the same approach I had. +1

Comment: possible improvements; first line: `max_digits = ceil(log2(max(num1,num2)));`, last line: `out = sum(pow2(mod(num1d+num2d,2), max_digits-1:-1:0))`

Comment: @Amro Thanks, `ceil` part was a bug indeed! I think I will keep the `out` part as it is though just because it is concise :)

Comment: @Amro typos typos! :) Well also I am trying really hard to have the comments squeezed in without introducing the horizontal scrollbar ;)

Comment: I hate those scrollbars too! You should have kept `a` and `b` as variable names :)

Comment: @Amro yeah I started with `a1`, `a2`, but then they don't make so much of sense, so I got to `num1` and `num2`. Anywho! It's all good now :)